# PHP Converting an Array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have an array or arrays that looks like this in php:
[image]

Is there an efficient way in php to extract just the numbers and get a new array that looks like this:

```
$new_array = array(2314, 3863, 4611, 4612, 24749, 21540...)
```

I can get it if I loop through, go into each array and push the number to another array but that seems like a very convoluted and messy way of doing it. So I was wondering if there is a better way in php or cakephp.

Comment: have you **tried anything** yourself so far?

Comment: `array_column` I suppose

Comment: Yeah, I can get it if I loop through, go into each array and push the number to another array but that seems like a very convoluted and messy way of doing it. So I wanted to see if anyone knew of a better way in php.

Comment: _efficient way_ This is the new code for ___do it for me___ right

Comment: A loop is convoluted and messy? A loop is a fundamental programming concept. Any other solution to this is just a loop someone else wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged `cakephp`, Cake offers the `Hash` class which can do this for you.

```
$newArray = Hash::extract($viewable_collection_ids, '{n}.collection_id');
```

[Cake Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you have PHP 5 >= 5.5.0 or PHP 7 - use `array_column`:

```
$numbers = array_column($viewable_collection_ids, 'collection_id');
```

Otherwise `foreach` is an acceptable solution, or:

```
$numbers = array_map(function($v) { return $v['collection_id']; }, $viewable_collection_ids);
```

Comment: I should have specified the version, it is an older one. Looping through it is then.

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate through it and get every number.

```
<?php
$firstArray = /*...*/;
$newarray = array();
foreach($firstArray AS $key => $value) {
    $newarray[] = $value['collection_id'];
}
?>
```